# Is this script vulnerable to LFI (Local File Injection)?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I was wondering if this little snippet was subject to Local File Injection vulnerability.

```
<?php
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
include '/some/dir/prefix_'.$lang.'whatever';
```

I know the whatever can be ignore by putting '%00' (Null byte) in the request. But if there is no sub-directory beginning with 'prefix_' in the /some/dir/ directory, can the exploit occur? How?

Thanks in advance for the anwser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$lang .= 'en/../../../../../etc/passwd' . 0x00;
```

You can avoid this by

```
$path = '/some/dir/prefix_'.$_GET['path'].'whatever';
$path = realpath($path);
if (($path !== false) && (strncmp('/dir/some/prefix_', $path, 17) === 0)) {
  // $path is fine
}
```

This tests, if the path exists and if its really under the directory-tree, that you allow it to be. It should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I mean somthing like, this. But not like this. The directory /some/dir/prefix_xy/ doesn't exists. How can the file system resolve /some/dir/prefix_xy/../ to /some/dir/?

Comment: It was an example. Maybe one use `en` instead of `xy` (Ive changed it in my answer). Now `prefix_en` exists and `..` works fine again. You can't trust it, anyway ;)

Comment: I'm quoting myself: " there is no sub-directory beginning with 'prefix_' in the /some/dir/ directory". So there is no /some/dir/prefix_en/ directory. The "whatever" points to a file.

Comment: Also the check can be wrong. realpath('/var/somehing') can return '/mnt/somethingelse/'.

Answer (score 2):

Using user input directly in your code is always dangerous.
It would be better to make it check if the value is in an array of acceptable values.

Comment: I know, this does not answer my question, not even remotely.

Comment: this answer should be accepted. If you don't know how to use exploit, it doesn't mean that exploit unusable. Rule is simple: don't trust user's input. Without any exceptions.

Comment: I know. I'm not using this code, I'm trying to learn and understand. I'm curious.
This is not an answer I was expecting.

Comment: Just because it was not an answer you were not expecting, that doesn't make it bad or wrong. Although this post does not answer the question you posed, it provides good guidance on input validation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can white list this one, something like

```
$possible_languages = array('en','fr','pt'); #preferably not hardcoded
$lang = $_GET['lang']
if( in_array($lang, $possible_languages) ){
     # do your thing
}
else {
    #error out
}
```

Basically... never trust user input.

Comment: Same comment as above (the one to gnur).